# Error when run "yarn run webpack:prod" TypeError: Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined

Tags: npm, jhipster, yarnpkg

> yarn run v1.1.0
>   $ yarn run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile
>   warning From Yarn 1.0 onwards, scripts don't require "--" for options to be forwarded. In a future version, any explicit "--" will be forwarded as-is to the scripts.
>   Starting compilation using the angular compiler.
>   (node:18420) DeprecationWarning: Chunk.modules is deprecated. Use Chunk.getNumberOfModules/mapModules/forEachModule/containsModule instead.
>   Angular compilation done, starting webpack bundling.
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined
>       at checkUnreachable (E:\worckspace\cloud9ers\cmis\node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:20770:31)
>       at bindChildrenWorker (E:\worckspace\cloud9ers\cmis\node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:19014:17)
>       at bindChildren (E:\worckspace\cloud9ers\cmis\node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:18969:17)
>       at bind (E:\worckspace\cloud9ers\cmis\node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:20199:21)
>       at bindSourceFile (E:\worckspace\cloud9ers\cmis\node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:18588:17)
>       at Object.bindSourceFile (E:\worckspace\cloud9ers\cmis\node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:18539:9)
>       at initializeTypeChecker (E:\worckspace\cloud9ers\cmis\node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:44253:20)
>       at Object.createTypeChecker (E:\worckspace\cloud9ers\cmis\node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:23058:9)
>       at getDiagnosticsProducingTypeChecker (E:\worckspace\cloud9ers\cmis\node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:70194:93)
>       at Object.getGlobalDiagnostics (E:\worckspace\cloud9ers\cmis\node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:70570:53)
>       at Tsc.typeCheck (E:\worckspace\cloud9ers\cmis\node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\src\tsc.js:166:23)
>       at E:\worckspace\cloud9ers\cmis\node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\src\main.js:122:23
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
>   error Command failed with exit code 1.
>   error Command failed with exit code 1.
>   info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this >command.

How can I fix this bug ?

Comment: Show us you webpack/webpack.prod.js and your file tree.

Comment: [webpack.prod.js](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OcX65kw8DNVqO8SBHPKmSIvMXk__XS40/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @ChrisR
do you want tree of `webpack.prod.js` file or for all project ?

Comment: @ChrisR this command run successfully due to last week and after that failed.

Comment: @MostafaElShafaey have you found the solution?